# Redirect loop after login

Tags: php, loops, symfony, authentication, firewall

**After login**, I want to access to the same page. But I have a redirect loop of death

security.yml

```
    login:
        pattern: ^/admin/login
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            form_login:
                check_path: _login_check
                login_path: _admin_login
                default_target_path: _admin_dashboard
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path:   _admin_logout
                target: _admin_login
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

routing.yml :

```
_admin_secured:
    resource: "@TestBackBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php"
    type:     annotation

_admin_home:
    resource: "@TestBackBundle/Controller/DashboardController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

DashboardController.php :

```
...

/**
 * @Route("/admin/dashboard")
 */
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_admin_dashboard")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

and SecuredController.php :

```
...

/**
 * @Route("/admin")
 */
class SecuredController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="_admin_login")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $request->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return array(
            'last_username' => $request->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_check", name="_login_check")
     */
    public function securityCheckAction()
    {
        // The security layer will intercept this request
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="_admin_logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        // The security layer will intercept this request
    }
}
```

What I did wrong ?

Comment: it happened also to me, my problem was that /admin/login is also insecured_area firewall, and symfony takes this first than the access_control one

Comment: and have you find a solution ?

Comment: I have one that it worked for me, I will post

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, the main difference is that your secured area is ^/admin, and mine it is ^/

There is a lot of redundant code, but I was tired to figure to make it works, and when it worked I just don't want to touch it anymore

(that it is in my case, I wanted to protect ^/ but anonymously access to /login, you are protecting /admin but want to access /admin/login)

```
firewalls:

        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        free:
            pattern: ^/$
            security: false

        free2:
            pattern: ^/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /borsa/ofertes
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

        login:
            pattern: ^/
            security: false
            anonymous: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I have add the login firewall but now I have this error after login: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Comment: eeeemmm.. no. this code is from my symfony project, you have to adapt at yours

Answer (score 0):

Add below section to your firewall before *secured_area*

```
my_login:
   pattern: ^/admin/login$
   security: false
   anonymous: true
```

You need to make the login page security off before defining the secured area
You also need to return a response not just array in your `indexAction`

```
/**
* @Route("/admin")
*/
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
   /**
   * @Route("/dashboard", name="_admin_dashboard")
   * @Template()
   */
   public function indexAction()
   {
      $response = new Response();
      $response->setContent(json_encode(array());
      return $response;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you set the `security: true` in secured_area as well?

Comment: if I write : `pattern : ^/admin/login` without `$` I have this error after login : The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

Comment: I add `security: true` in secured_area but same problem

Comment: Not me but you forgot to return a response in your `indexAction`; I updated my answer

Comment: the problem came from login_check action. I add your line in my indexAction but it doesn't work. I use annotation for indexAction.

Comment: @DOZ you are right because of using annotation you don't need to create a response object; but make sure that the templates you defined in `@Template()` are rendered correctly

Comment: yes `@Template()` works fine. But as I said, the issue here comes from  `login_check` because I have this error after login when `securityCheckAction` is called. But I think is always a firewall error...

Comment: Base on the documentation [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form] you just need to define the rout for `login_check` but should not create a `loginCheckAction` in controller. According to using annotation I don't know how to define just the route for `login_chekc` but no action

Comment: I have tried but I have another error : Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?   and I have added the route in my routing correctly like this : `login_check: pattern: /admin/login_check`

Comment: Could you update your question base on what you have done yet?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link which has same issue ([Google Group Question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony2/18XxYagnnug/eNSOeGodcgMJ))
I think you need to use the full path for login_check and login_path in your security.yml

```
check_path: ^/admin/login_check
login_path: ^/admin/login
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue : Should be added `$` after login path in `login` firewall and `access_control`:

```
login:
       pattern: ^/admin/login$
       security: false
       anonymous: true


access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

I hope this will help other people !